# How to a implement ListBox ScrollIntoView functionality in a ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a screen with a `TextBox` in which the user can type a 2-character state code.  Below the `TextBox` is a `ListBox` containing all 50 state codes.  The `TextBox` is bound to property in the VM, and the `SelectedItem` is bound to a property in the VM.  That all works fine.

The way I want the UI to work is when the user selects a state from the `ListBox`, the `TextBox` is automatically filled in, and this works fine.

Where it gets messy is when the user types in the state in the `TextBox`.  When I get the first character, what I want to do is reposition the list box at the first matching state code for that letter, so for instance, if the `ListBox` is sitting at "AK" (Alaska) and the user is going to type "ID" for Idaho, when I get the "I" I want to position the `ListBox` so you can see the first "I" state, which is "IA" (Iowa).

If I use *code behind* and point `SelectionChanged=BringSelectionIntoView` with this method coded as follows, it works great:

```
private void BringSelectionIntoView(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox lb = (ListBox)sender;
    lb.ScrollIntoView(lb.SelectedItem);
}
```

All I have to do is scan the list of state codes until the first letter matches, then update the `Index` property to which `SelectedIndex` is bound, and poof, the `BringSelectionIntoView()` method gets invoked and I have exactly the UI behavior I want.

Trying to do this in a purest MVVM methodology, however, has proved quite frustrating.  I'm not using MVVMLight or ExpressionBlend--I want a simple way to do this in MVVM.  I understand the *purest's* mindset of not putting any UI code in the view, but the framework is insanely cumbersome to enact this kind of behavior.  There's a point of diminishing returns when you have to create such obtuse plumbing to force yourself to adhere to a pattern when it's far more practical to put in the method with 2 lines of code that works perfectly.

So my question is this: am I doing something wrong and is there a simple way to make this work without violating MVVM?  It's disappointing if the solution requires additional SDKs or someone's framework. That would suggest that MVVM doesn't have particularly good legs to stand on in a generic OOP sense.

Does someone see an error in what I'm trying to do, or do you see a simplistic solution here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVVM is not about not having any code behind.

What you're talking about here is VIEW behavior. Which fits perfectly in the code behind, as long as you're not messing with the DATA in the event handlers.

You're using a VIEW event handler to manipulate a VIEW aspect.

That doesn't break MVVM.

Keep it that way. Keep it Simple.

You should still have a ViewModel and a Model to hold the DATA that the UI shows.

Comment: Aha, okay, this is an answer I like! Thanks!  I was trying everything to get around having any code in the View, and it felt like I was creating a battery-powered ashtray with 17 moving parts and an owner's manual, when all I really wanted was a simple ashtray.

Your response makes sense, and using a 2-line solution in lieu of building a large class to solve this one minor (but requested) feature, well, I think the cards pretty much play themselves here.

Thank you!

Comment: @John Still, Remember you must NOT put Business logic or data related code in the code behind.

Comment: Yes, that absolutely makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for an attached behavior. You can write this behavior once and use it for all listboxes without ever having to write any additional code. If you would like me to elaborate, ask and I'll post more information.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I looked at some articles on behavior, and I mocked up some code only to discover I needed (in the example I was following) to install Expression Blend.  Is there another way to get behavior-based functionality?

Comment: @John Behaviors are part of the [Expression SDK](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Expression.Blend.SDK.WPF/) which can be installed separately with no need to install Expression Blend.

Comment: I'll look into the Expression SDK, as I'm sure it will make many MVVM tasks a lot easier, but by the same token, a fundamentally sound pattern should rely on it's algorithmic elegance and not a vendor's SDK, in my humble opinion.  That said, I'm not adverse to using better tools to get the job done.  +1 for the suggestion and link!

Comment: @Michael - I am installing the Expression SDK and will look at behaviors.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @John: There are two types of behaviors in WPF. There are the ones that come with the Expression SDK. Then there are ones which just use dependency properties. I usually see the term "attached behavior" for the latter. I'm not sure if there's a more concise term for the former. See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF) for the "attached behavior" idea.